# Apache .htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Need to redirect with params. 
From https://api.example.com/method/method.name?v=5.80 
To https://api.example.com/method.php?v=5.80

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /method/
RewriteRule ^/method/$ method.php?m=%1 [L]
```

That does not work :c

Comment: 404 error with that rule

Comment: The query string does not contain `/method/`, so the RewriteCond never matches. You don't need to actually match the query string, so you don't need a RewriteCond at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to want to append the same query string to the new target url, you don't need to use `RewriteCond` . You only need to redirect the old uri `/method/method.name` to `/method.php` .

You  can use the following RewriteRule  for this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^method/method.name/?$ /method.php [L,R]
```